# Get OnMouseDown to work with a 2D Polygon Collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouseevent

I'm having a hell of time getting a 2D polygon collider to register a mouse click. I've attached images and code to show where I'm at. I cannot get the click to work.

Ultimately, the thing I'm trying to achieve is to just set the area defined by the collider to be clickable rather than the entire image sprite.

What am I doing wrong here? Need help!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log ("Clicked the Collider!");
    }
}
```

I've defined the collider:
[image: I've defined the collider]

I've setup the components for my image:
[image: I've setup the components for my image]

Comment: It's a Game Development question, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: @ntohl unity3d is a tag in Stackoverflow

Comment: @greyBow try using Physics.Raycast instead. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Comment: @ntohl Unity3D questions are more than welcome here.

Comment: Does the problem still exist if you change the shape of collider to something more common (just box over image)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using the new uGUI system, you dont even need colliders!
Make your script look like this and you should be able to do it with any object that has `Image` component. so you can get rid of the collider!

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MouseClick : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData data)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Clicked the Collider!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Gett error: `UnityEngine.GUI' is a type not a namespace. A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces`

Comment: Also, the thing I'm trying to achieve isn't getting the entire image to be clickable, its just getting the area defined by the collider to be clickable. Does that explanation make sense?

Comment: Sorry its `UnityEngine.UI;` fixed. Also you traced your image exactly... If you want a separate area to be clickable then draw an image shaped exactly like the clickable area you want and make it transparent. Isn't that wayyy easier than adjusting meshes to the clickable area you want?

Comment: Whenever I create a sprite from an image in Unity, the bounding box is always rectangular, making the clickable area rectangular as well. How do override that and draw an an image shaped like the clickable area? I'm missing something obviously.

Comment: Did you miss the answer I posted? "Make your script look like this and you should be able to do it with any object that has Image component" `OnPointerClick()` fires the event from the rendered area of `Image`

Comment: How does it know where the rendered area is? Using your code it registers a click everywhere in the image, including the 'clear' space.

Comment: That functionality is all done through the new Canvas system and is hidden. Just make sure your game object is inside of a canvas and has `Image` component attached.`PointerEventData data` will give you all sorts of nice methods/fields as well like `data.position` which is the mouse position. See them all here http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData.html

Comment: What could Be going wrong for me then? Why is the clear space around my image registering the click?

Comment: i havent opened Unity in a while but check the imported picture itself, it might have to be set to sprite or advanced or something like that. I can assure you that shouldne be happening though, i have used this technique many times.

Comment: I guess I'm out of options. My image texture type is Sprite (2D and UI). I made sure the space around my image is indeed transparent, I'm using your code snippet, yet the clear space around the image is still registering a click.

Comment: You know what, i just read into it and its not a default behavior of unity, but you can still achieve this with a user's script here: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/none-rectangle-shaped-button.263684/#post-1744521

Comment: Best $15 dollars I've spent this week! https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/28601. This solves my whole conundrum. Thanks for the help in any case though. I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, i gotta buy that too.

Answer (score 3):

Set your Canvas "Render mode" to "Screen Space Camera" and attach your camera,

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest to you a different approach seeing as this uses UGUI.

Attach an EventTrigger script. Then add a new trigger of type PointerClick. Now you can drag an object into that and call any function on that object. This is a very easy and reusable way.

With this in place you can safely remove you rigidbody and collider unless those are needed for something other than mouse interaction.